# Max Drawdown with Minimum Window Length

Tags: python, algorithm

For a given time series of floats, it is pretty easy to calculate an unconstrained maximum drawdown in `O(n)` time, where max drawdown is defined as

```
\min_{i,j, i<j}(x_j - x_i)
```

In python, we the calculation is `min(x - numpy.expanding_max(x))`, but to get a `O(n)` algo write it explicitly:

```
def max_drawdown(s):
    drawdn = 0
    m,M = s[0],s[0]
    t1,t2 = 0,0
    T1,T2 = 0,0
    for i,v in enumerate(s):
        if (v < m):
            if (v-m) < drawdn:
                drawdn = v-m
                t2 = i
                T1,T2 = t1,t2
        else:
            m = v
            t1 = i
    return T1,T2,drawdn
```

Is there an `O(n)` algorithm for a max_drawdown that is constrained to have window duration > min_length? In this case I want \min_{i,j, (j-i) > min_length}(x_j - x_i).

Note that this is not a "rolling drawdown" calculation as in [Compute *rolling* maximum drawdown of pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058333/compute-rolling-maximum-drawdown-of-pandas-series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifications are quite small compared to your `max_drawdown` function. The current algorithm can be written in pseudocode

```
Iterate over list
  if (current_element > maximum)
    maximum = current_element
  if (current element - maximum < drawdn)
    drawdn = current_element-maximum
```

Now instead of searching the `max_drawdown` at same index we search for the maximum value we need to have a distance of `min_length` with those indexes. In Python this becomes:

```
def max_drawdown_min_lenght(s,min_length):
    min_length += 1 #this is for i-j > l (not i-j >= l)
    drawdn = 0
    m = s[0]
    t1 = 0
    T1,T2 = 0,0
    for i in range(len(s)-min_length):
        if (s[i] >= m): #do we have new maximum?
            m = s[i]
            t1 = i
        if (s[i+min_length]-m) < drawdn:#do we have new max drawdown?
            drawdn = s[i+min_length]-m
            T1,T2 = t1,i+min_length
    return T1,T2,drawdn
```

Comment: Yes - this is conceptually slightly different, looking forward from the max instead of backwards from the current iterate. It works, and is simpler than my solution which I didn't post. Thx!