# mark a value from matplotlib plot by changing the color backgorund and tracing lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Let's say I have these two arrays that I've plotted with **matplotlib**

**Distance** = [vlaue1; value2; value3...]

**focus_measurement** = [vlaue1; value2; value3...]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAlqU.png)

Using this code:

```
plt.plot(Distance, focus_measurement)
plt.xlabel('Distance (cm)'),plt.ylabel('Variance'), plt.title('Capteur')
plt.show()
```

Which gives this graph..

What I want to do now is to highlight the region of all the values greater than **1200** in the **Variance** and their equivalent in **focus_measurement**.

**EDIT:**

this is how you do it:

You add this line of code for the x axis:

```
plt.axvspan(180,300, facecolor="red", alpha=0.5)
```

Or this one for the y axis:

```
plt.axhspan(1200,1500, facecolor="red", alpha=0.5)
```

Which will give something like..

```
plt.plot(Distance, focus_measurement)
plt.xlabel('Distance (cm)'),plt.ylabel('Variance'), 
plt.title('Capteur')
plt.axvspan(180,300, facecolor="red", alpha=0.5)
plt.axhspan(1200,1500, facecolor="red", alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your desired outcome is not clear. Do you want to change the colour of the line for values that have a variance greater than 1200?

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270981/in-a-matplotlib-plot-can-i-highlight-specific-x-value-ranges)?

Comment: Exactly ! I want to change the colour background of all the valeus greater than 1200 in variance and their equivalence in distance

Comment: @GWW Yupe ! this is it  ! Thank'x a lot sure.

Comment: @MouradOverFlow As you have figured out the answer it is better to post it as an answer then mark it as accepted rather than editing your question.

Comment: @DavidG Ok, I just posted an answer but I could not mark it as accepted, I don't not why.

Comment: @MouradOverFlow You might have to wait a few minutes before you can accept it

Comment: @DavidG OK man ! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

You add this line of code for the x axis:

```
plt.axvspan(180,300, facecolor="red", alpha=0.5)
```

Or this one for the y axis:

```
plt.axhspan(1200,1500, facecolor="red", alpha=0.5)
```

Which will give something like..

```
plt.plot(Distance, focus_measurement)
plt.xlabel('Distance (cm)'),plt.ylabel('Variance'), 
plt.title('Capteur')
plt.axvspan(180,300, facecolor="red", alpha=0.5)
plt.axhspan(1200,1500, facecolor="red", alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```