# Matplotlib: How to skip a range of hours when plotting with a datetime axis?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have tick-by-tick data of a financial instrument, which I am trying to plot using `matplotlib`. I am working with `pandas` and the data is indexed with `DatetimeIndex`.

The problem is, when I try to plot multiple trading days I can't skip the range of time between the market closing time and next day's opening (see the example), which of course I am not interested in.

Is there a way to make matplotlib ignore this and just "stick" together the closing quote with the following day's opening? I tried to pass a custom range of time:

```
plt.xticks(time_range)
```

But the result is the same. Any ideas how to do this?

```
# Example data
instrument = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Datetime': [
        dt.datetime.strptime('2018-01-11 11:00:11', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        dt.datetime.strptime('2018-01-11 13:02:17', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        dt.datetime.strptime('2018-01-11 16:59:14', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),

        dt.datetime.strptime('2018-01-12 11:00:11', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        dt.datetime.strptime('2018-01-12 13:15:24', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        dt.datetime.strptime('2018-01-12 16:58:43', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    ],
    'Price': [127.6, 128.1, 127.95, 129.85, 129.7, 131.2],
    'Volume': [725, 146, 48, 650, 75, 160]
}).set_index('Datetime')

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
top = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0, 0), rowspan=3, colspan=4)
bottom = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (3,0), rowspan=1, colspan=4)
top.plot(instrument.index, instrument['Price'])
bottom.bar(instrument.index, instrument['Volume'], 0.005) 

top.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
top.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
top.set_title('Example')
top.set_ylabel('Price')
bottom.set_ylabel('Volume')
```

[image: example]

Comment: When inquiring about some undesired beheviour you need to provide a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: I added some code. I think the behaviour is not undesired in the sense that it is the default behaviour; it's me who is trying to produce a different result.

Comment: Ok that wasnt clear. I guess you have two options: plot two or more subplots (see [broken axis example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html)) or use a new continuous index to plot against; the latter would then require you to set the ticklabels manually as a subset of the original date index.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

Replace the matplotlib plotting functions:

```
top.plot(instrument.index, instrument['Price'])
bottom.bar(instrument.index, instrument['Volume'], 0.005)
```

With these ones:

```
top.plot(range(instrument.index.size), instrument['Price'])
bottom.bar(range(instrument.index.size), instrument['Volume'], width=1)
```

Or with these pandas plotting functions (only the x-axis limits will look different):

```
instrument['Price'].plot(use_index=False, ax=top)
instrument['Volume'].plot.bar(width=1, ax=bottom)
```

Align both plots by sharing the x-axis with `sharex=True` and set up the ticks as you would like them using the dataframe index, as shown in the example further below.

---

Let me first create a sample dataset and show what it looks like if I plot it using matplotlib plotting functions like in your example where the `DatetimeIndex` is used as the x variable.

**Create sample dataset**

The sample data is created using the [pandas_market_calendars](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-market-calendars/) package to create a realistic `DatetimeIndex` with a minute-by-minute frequency that spans several weekdays and a weekend.

```
import numpy as np                        # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd                       # v 1.1.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt           # v 3.3.2
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal    # v 1.6.1

# Create datetime index with a 'minute start' frequency based on the New
# York Stock Exchange trading hours (end date is inclusive)
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
nyse_schedule = nyse.schedule(start_date='2021-01-07', end_date='2021-01-11')
nyse_dti = mcal.date_range(nyse_schedule, frequency='1min', closed='left')\
               .tz_convert(nyse.tz.zone)
# Remove timestamps of closing times to create a 'period start' datetime index
nyse_dti = nyse_dti.delete(nyse_dti.indexer_at_time('16:00'))

# Create sample of random data consisting of opening price and
# volume of financial instrument traded for each period
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1234)  # random number generator
price_change = rng.normal(scale=0.1, size=nyse_dti.size)
price_open = 127.5 + np.cumsum(price_change)
volume = rng.integers(100, 10000, size=nyse_dti.size)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(Price=price_open, Volume=volume), index=nyse_dti)
```

```
df.head()

#                             Price       Volume
#  2021-01-07 09:30:00-05:00  127.339616  7476
#  2021-01-07 09:31:00-05:00  127.346026  3633
#  2021-01-07 09:32:00-05:00  127.420115  1339
#  2021-01-07 09:33:00-05:00  127.435377  3750
#  2021-01-07 09:34:00-05:00  127.521752  7354
```

**Plot data with matplotlib using the DatetimeIndex**

This sample data can now be plotted using matplotlib plotting functions like in your example, but note that the subplots are created by using [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) with the `sharex=True` argument. This aligns the line with the bars correctly and makes it possible to use the interactive interface of matplotlib with both subplots.

```
# Create figure and plots using matplotlib functions
fig, (top, bot) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(10,5),
                               gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[0.75,0.25]))
top.plot(df.index, df['Price'])
bot.bar(df.index, df['Volume'], 0.0008)

# Set title and labels
top.set_title('Matplotlib plots with unwanted gaps', pad=20, size=14, weight='semibold')
top.set_ylabel('Price', labelpad=10)
bot.set_ylabel('Volume', labelpad=10);
```

[image: mpl_plots_gaps]

**Plot data with matplotlib without any gaps by using a range of integers**

The problem of these gaps can be solved by simply ignoring the `DatetimeIndex` and using a range of integers instead. Most of the work then lies in creating appropriate tick labels. Here is an example:

```
# Create figure and matplotlib plots with some additional formatting
fig, (top, bot) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(10,5),
                               gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[0.75,0.25]))
top.plot(range(df.index.size), df['Price'])
top.set_title('Matplotlib plots without any gaps', pad=20, size=14, weight='semibold')
top.set_ylabel('Price', labelpad=10)
top.grid(axis='x', alpha=0.3)
bot.bar(range(df.index.size), df['Volume'], width=1)
bot.set_ylabel('Volume', labelpad=10)

# Set fixed major and minor tick locations
ticks_date = df.index.indexer_at_time('09:30')
ticks_time = np.arange(df.index.size)[df.index.minute == 0][::2] # step in hours
bot.set_xticks(ticks_date)
bot.set_xticks(ticks_time, minor=True)

# Format major and minor tick labels
labels_date = [maj_tick.strftime('\n%d-%b').replace('\n0', '\n')
               for maj_tick in df.index[ticks_date]]
labels_time = [min_tick.strftime('%I %p').lstrip('0').lower()
               for min_tick in df.index[ticks_time]]
bot.set_xticklabels(labels_date)
bot.set_xticklabels(labels_time, minor=True)
bot.figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=0, ha='center', which='both')
```

[image: mpl_plots_nogaps]

**Create dynamic ticks for interactive plots**

If you like to use the interactive interface of matplotlib (with pan/zoom), you will need to use locators and formatters from the [matplotlib ticker](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module. Here is an example of how to set the ticks, where the major ticks are fixed and formatted like above but the minor ticks are generated automatically as you zoom in/out of the plot:

```
# Set fixed major tick locations and automatic minor tick locations
ticks_date = df.index.indexer_at_time('09:30')
bot.set_xticks(ticks_date)
bot.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())

# Format major tick labels
labels_date = [maj_tick.strftime('\n%d-%b').replace('\n0', '\n')
               for maj_tick in df.index[ticks_date]]
bot.set_xticklabels(labels_date)

# Format minor tick labels
def min_label(x, pos):
    if 0 <= x < df.index.size:
        return df.index[int(x)].strftime('%H:%M')
min_fmtr = ticker.FuncFormatter(min_label)
bot.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(min_fmtr)

bot.figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=0, ha='center', which='both')
```

---

Documentation: [example of an alternative solution](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_index_formatter2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-date-index-formatter2-py); [datetime string format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/ 
Allows mimicking the usual financial plots you see in most services.

When you call the mplfinance `mpf.plot()` function, there is a kwarg `show_nontrading`, which by default is set to `False` so that these unwanted gaps are automatically *not* plotted.  (To plot them, set `show_nontrading=True`).

Comment: Link-only answers are not appropriate. You could give an example of code using this library that would answer the question.

Comment: Thanks! Considering that the mplfinance page at PyPI provides complete documentation, with this helpful pointer about the `show_nontrading` flag for the `plot()` function, it's a great start. Good to see someone's approached this already, and there's even the support for Renko charts