# Dataframe plot - straight lines due to date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dataframe which drops data in non-business hours however while plotting the dataframe since date is index the plot shows a long connecting lines (see picture) between previous day last reading and next day first reading. I need to avoid this and plot only business hours.
I am using following simple code

```
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

**Dataframe output**

```
date                      NIFTY 50  AARTIIND  ...  DIVISLAB  GARFIBRES
                                           ...                     
2021-08-31 12:15:00+05:30  1.000000  1.000000  ...  1.000000   1.000000
2021-08-31 13:15:00+05:30  0.999627  0.996703  ...  1.002769   0.999557
2021-08-31 14:15:00+05:30  1.005706  0.996916  ...  1.005469   0.986966
2021-08-31 15:15:00+05:30  1.005078  0.997607  ...  1.004459   0.994337
2021-09-01 09:15:00+05:30  1.009123  1.003882  ...  1.006013   0.995697
2021-09-01 10:15:00+05:30  1.003989  0.990428  ...  1.005382   0.995413
2021-09-01 11:15:00+05:30  1.003241  0.993566  ...  1.021187   0.997517
2021-09-01 12:15:00+05:30  1.002904  0.986759  ...  1.018506   0.997184
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the dataframe, your error and your expected output

Comment: Luke, I have printed the dataframe output in the question and now also uploaded the image which is expected output. I need to drop the non-business length of the plot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a workaround to the problem. I have changed the format of date index as shown. This has helped me to get exactly whats seen in data frame n the plot. Thanks for you help and if there is any other better way please suggest.

My modified code

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M')
print(df)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: Updated plot]

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dataframe like this one, with date on index and some columns with values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start = '2021-01-01', end = '2021-01-05', freq = 'H')})
df['value 1'] = np.random.random(len(df))
df['value 2'] = np.random.random(len(df))
df = df.set_index('date')
```

```
                      value 1   value 2
date                                   
2021-01-01 00:00:00  0.374540  0.427541
2021-01-01 01:00:00  0.950714  0.025419
2021-01-01 02:00:00  0.731994  0.107891
2021-01-01 03:00:00  0.598658  0.031429
2021-01-01 04:00:00  0.156019  0.636410
2021-01-01 05:00:00  0.155995  0.314356
2021-01-01 06:00:00  0.058084  0.508571
2021-01-01 07:00:00  0.866176  0.907566
2021-01-01 08:00:00  0.601115  0.249292
2021-01-01 09:00:00  0.708073  0.410383
```

You can define start and end time of the job and use them to filter your dataframe; where hour is out of this bound, you set data to `None`:

```
start_working_hour = 8
end_working_hour = 17
filt = (df.index.hour < start_working_hour) | (df.index.hour > end_working_hour)
df.loc[filt] = None
```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start = '2021-01-01', end = '2021-01-05', freq = 'H')})
df['value 1'] = np.random.random(len(df))
df['value 2'] = np.random.random(len(df))
df = df.set_index('date')


start_working_hour = 8
end_working_hour = 17
filt = (df.index.hour < start_working_hour) | (df.index.hour > end_working_hour)
df.loc[filt] = None

df.plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you want to remove white gaps between lines so as to have continuous lines, taking inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48250054/9214357), you should plot using `range(df.index.size)` as x axis, then you need to adjust x ticks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import time


df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start = '2021-01-01', end = '2021-01-05', freq = 'H')})
df['value 1'] = np.random.random(len(df))
df['value 2'] = np.random.random(len(df))
df = df.set_index('date')


start_working_hour = 8
end_working_hour = 16
hour_step = 2
filt = (start_working_hour <= df.index.hour) & (df.index.hour <= end_working_hour)
df = df.loc[filt]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 5))

ax.plot(range(df.index.size), df['value 1'], label = 'value 1')
ax.plot(range(df.index.size), df['value 2'], label = 'value 2')

ax.grid(axis='x', alpha=0.3)

ticks_date = df.index.indexer_at_time(time(start_working_hour).strftime('%H:%M'))
ticks_time = np.arange(df.index.size)[df.index.minute == 0][::hour_step]
ax.set_xticks(ticks_date)
ax.set_xticks(ticks_time, minor=True)

labels_date = [maj_tick.strftime('\n%d-%b').replace('\n0', '\n') for maj_tick in df.index[ticks_date]]
labels_time = [min_tick.strftime('%H:%M') for min_tick in df.index[ticks_time]]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels_date)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels_time, minor=True)
ax.figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=0, ha='center', which='both')

ax.legend(frameon = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Zephyr for your answer. If you look at my dataframe output it neatly shows filtered data. However when I plot the dataframe it results in the long drawn straight lines making up for the time lost between . I am looking for continuous plot.       2021-08-31 15:15:00+05:30  1.005078  0.997607  ...  1.004459   0.994337
2021-09-01 09:15:00+05:30  1.009123  1.003882  ...  1.006013   0.995697                                                          I essentially want to shorten the length of x axis

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you want to remove the white gap between the discontinuous lines so as to have a continuous lines?

Comment: yes I want to avoid the while spaces and have continuous lines

Comment: I have also tried to answer with a workaround which worked for me. Thanks for your help.