# Reverse of scipy find_peaks to find upturns, rather than downturns

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Im trying to highlight downturns and upturns along a time series of a rolling average. I was able to highlight downturns using scipy's `find_peaks`, using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66102371/23283438). Is there a way to highlight this inversely?

```
ax = df['x_rolling'].plot(figsize=(10, 5), use_index = True, ylabel='Net Sales (USD)')
plt.title('Order Net Sales (Rolling average: 4 weeks)')
ax.grid(axis='x', alpha=0.3)

w = 7
p = np.std(data2)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(df['x_rolling'], width=w, prominence=p)
troughs, _ = find_peaks(-df['x_rolling'], width=w, prominence=p)

for peak, trough in zip(peaks, troughs):
    x1 = df.iloc[trough].name
    x2 = df.iloc[peak].name
    ax.axvspan(x1, x2, facecolor='red', alpha=0.2)
    ax.axvline(x2, color='green', alpha=0.6, label = str(x2))
    ax.axvline(x1, color='red', alpha=0.6, label=str(x1))
```

Downturns on time series highlighted:

[image]

Referencing my plot, essentially is there a way to fill from the red to green lines, opposed to from green to red lines.

Comment: What about `ax.axvspan(x1[:-1], x2[1:], facecolor="green", alpha=0.2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the inverse area shaded by looping through the reverse of each series as the following

```
for peak, trough in zip(reversed(peaks), reversed(troughs)):
```